# Possible bug when when using empty as image?

Tags: modeling, 3d-view, wireframe

I'm using empty as image for set up of blueprints for car modeling. When I toggle between solid and wireframe in the viewport the images strange things happens with the images! Please look at the second image below. Is this a bug or could it be avoided? I'm not using the x-ray option.

In solid mode:
[image]

In wireframe mode:
[image]

Comment: I think it is better using the backgound panel.

Comment: @LeoNas But then I can't see the blueprints in a perspective view!

Comment: Try using Images As Planes addon instead, empty images indeed have this limitation